# Netbeans not using available memory during compilation

Tags: java, performance, netbeans, compilation, heap-memory

Using NetBeans on linux, compiling a program ~6000 lines long, and appear to have reached a threshold of some sort.  Compilation time has jumped from about one minute to over 25.

It's clearly a memory issue, the IDE is taking 300Meg and not one byte more, despite clearly needing to.
I've added `-J-Xmx600m` to the `netbeans.conf` file, and modified the `xms` command to `132m`, but although the log file reports:

```
Compiler: HotSpot Client Compiler
Heap memory usage: initial 132.0MB maximum 580.0MB
Non heap memory usage: initial 160.0kB maximum -1b
Garbage collector: Copy (Collections=23 Total time spent=1s)
Garbage collector: MarkSweepCompact (Collections=3 Total time spent=0s)
```

It's clearly not working.

Is there any configuration option in the IDE itself which I need to be tinkering with?

Comment: *`Compilation time has jumped from about one minute to over 25...`* When? After increasing maximum heap memory? Did you change the code/program??

Comment: A program 6000 lines long? Do you mean to tell us that you have a single source file with 6000 lines?

Comment: Unfortunately such source files exists even in popular projects: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.framework/4.6.1/org/apache/felix/framework/Felix.java?av=f

Comment: Have you verified this program compiles quickly with `javac`?

Comment: "Did you change the code/program?"  Yes, I added a few lines of code to display some information graphically.

Comment: "Do you mean to tell us that you have a single source file with 6000 lines".  No, the total number of lines in the thirteen classes which comprise the program is around 6000.  Why is that relevant?

Comment: "Have you verified this program compiles quickly with javac?"  No, it fails to compile at all, and unless there's no alternative I'm unwilling to spend the time to find out why.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to an incredibly helpful person on the netbeans user mailing list, who solved this for me.

It wasn't memory after all; but a bug in version 8u5 of the JDK.  I switched back down a couple of versions, and everything works perfectly now.